# Where does the IBM MFP Operational Analytics Console information come from?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm wondering where is located the info that feeds the graphs in the IBM MobileFirst Platform analytics tool. Is the MFP Analytics Console only reading information from logs? That means if I have a farm with two independent Analytics .war packages deployed, I need checking the information from all the nodes in the farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information that feeds the Analytics console graph are stored in the filesystem on the Analytics server. By default, it is stored in a directory named 
`analyticsData` in the application server folder. You can modify the path by changing the property `"analytics/datapath"` in the analytics server configuration.

You can see more details on the properties here : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.analytics.doc/analytics/c_config_properties.html

Comment: I marked this question as resolved, but do you know in MFP 7.1 where is this _analytics/datapath_ parameter located?

Comment: For v7.1, the properties are set in the similar way. More details here - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_properties.html

Answer (score 1):

The link below shows properties that you need to configure in each farm member to point where the analytics data needs to go to.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.analytics.doc/analytics/c_config_properties.html

Such as one of the property that is exposed by the MobileFirst Analytics Server that receives incoming analytics data. For example, http://:/analytics-service/rest/v2

mfp.analytics.url

Comment: I marked this question as resolved, but do you know in MFP 7.1 where is this analytics/datapath parameter located?